# How do I disbable screen touch in FireFox?

Tags: firefox, touch

I have a HP laptop with touchscreen. I want to disable touch in the FF browser (61.0.1) and only use mouse keyboard event. How can I do this?

In GC I can disable touch event via the URL:
`chrome://flags` and set `Touch Events API` to disabled.
What is the equivalent in FF?

Answer (score 1):

FF (61.0.1):

about:config: set dom.w3c_touch_events.enabled = 0